# PostgreSQL constraint violation error on ManyToMany relationship but foreign key should be present

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to set up a system very similar to the one shown here:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

The PostgreSQL schema is set up the same way with the content class shown below, mapping to the tag class in a table with a content_id and a tag_id which have foreign key constraints on their respective tables.  The issue I am having is when attempting to persist a new content object I am checking if the tags of the object exist and if they do I am adding them using the addTag method and then persisting the object.  Otherwise I create them and persist the object.  The POST method for doing this is also shown below.  The repository successfully finds the tags since they are already persisted but I get the following error when I attempt to then persist the content:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table

```
"content_tag" violates foreign key constraint "tag_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (tag_id)=(11) is not present in table "tag".
```

I stepped through the code and when the tags are added to the content using the addTag method it shows that their ids match the tags that are already in the database so I don't understand why when I persist the content it is a different id.  Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening and have the persisting of content work?

```
@Entity(name = "Content")
@Table(name = "content")
@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)
public class Content implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "StringJsonObject")
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "content_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="content_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
        tag.getContents().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.remove(tag);
        tag.getContents().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Content)) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Content) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Content> contents = new HashSet<>();

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Content> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(Set<Content> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Tag tag = (Tag) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, tag.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}

@PostMapping(value = "/content", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ContentJSON createContent(@RequestBody(required = false) final String payload) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(payload)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ServiceErrorCode.INVALID_REQUEST_BODY);
    }
    final ContentRequest request = convertPayloadToRequest(payload, ContentRequest.class);
    final Content content = new Content();
    content.setText(request.getContent().getText().toString());

    for (final String tag : request.getContent().getTags()) {
        final List<Tag> current = tagRepository.findByName(tag);
        if (current.isEmpty()) {
            final Tag newTag = new Tag(tag);
            tagRepository.save(newTag);
            content.addTag(newTag);
        } else {
            content.addTag(current.get(0));
        }

    }
    final Content response = contentRepository.save(content);

    Set<String> tagNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (final Tag tag : content.getTags()) {
        tagNames.add(tag.getName());
    }
    return new ContentJSON(response, tagNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the annotation below.

```
@JoinTable(name = "content_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "content_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
)
```

the joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns were reversed